# Spring.NET Unable to cast to type Spring.Collections.Set

Tags: c#, spring.net

I'm using Spring.NET to configure some objects, and I've written a FactoryObject to make configuring a Quartz.NET calendar bearable.

It has a property shown below, that of course we expect to configure with Spring.NET

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Quartz.Impl.Calendar;
using Spring.Objects.Factory;

namespace My.Package.TaskExecutorDemo
{

    /// <summary>
    /// TODO:
    /// </summary>
    public class WeeklyCalendarFactoryObject : WeeklyCalendar, IFactoryObject
    {
        private ISet<DayOfWeek> _daysOfWeek = new HashSet<DayOfWeek>();

        public ISet<DayOfWeek> DaysOfWeekExcluded
        {
            get { return _daysOfWeek; }
            set
            {
                if (value == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("DaysOfWeekExcluded");
                }
                _daysOfWeek = value;
            }
        }
        
        //Everything else ...
    }
}
```

It is configured by the following object definition.

```
<object id="weeklyCalendar" type="My.Package.TaskExecutorDemo.WeeklyCalendarFactoryObject, TaskExecutorDemo">
 <property name="DaysOfWeekExcluded">
   <set element-type="System.DayOfWeek, mscorlib">
     <value>Friday</value>
     <value>Saturday</value>
     <value>Sunday</value>
   </set>
 </property>
</object>
```

But at start up this throws the following exception:

> Spring.Objects.Factory.ObjectCreationException: Error creating object with name 'weeklyCalendar' defined in 'config [C:\Users\username\some\path\TaskExecutorDemo\bin\Debug\TaskExecutorDemo.exe.Config#spring/objects] line 7' : Initialization of object failed : Unable to cast object of type System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[System.DayOfWeek]' to type 'Spring.Collections.ISet'.
>
> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[System.DayOfWeek]' to type 'Spring.Collections.ISet'.

But I don't reference `Spring.Collections.ISet` anywhere in my code.  How do I get Spring.NET to configure my `ISet` property correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs on [setting generic collection values](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-generic-collections-values) is not supported for `ISet<T>`; only the generic collections `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` and `IList<T>` are supported. Try passing an explicit configuring an explicit `HashSet<T>` using the [constructor taking an `IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301504.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for the information.  Can you specify what versions of .NET support the casting of a `string` to an `enum`?

Comment: Conversion for enums works [out-of-the-box](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-type-conversion-enums). Under the hood, spring.net uses [`System.ComponentModel.EnumConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.enumconverter.aspx); available since .net 1.0 so that probably has always worked. My mistake; I'll remove that from my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`Set` section in your xml-config creates `Spring.Collections.ISet` object

Try this:

```xml
<object id="weeklyCalendar" type="My.Package.TaskExecutorDemo.WeeklyCalendarFactoryObject, TaskExecutorDemo">
  <property name="DaysOfWeekExcluded">
    <object type="System.Collections.Generic.HashSet&lt;System.DayOfWeek>">
      <constructor-arg name="collection" type="System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable&lt;System.DayOfWeek>">
        <list element-type="System.DayOfWeek">
          <value>Friday</value>
          <value>Saturday</value>
          <value>Sunday</value>
        </list>
      </constructor-arg>
    </object>
  </property>
</object>
```

Comment: Do the string values parse into `DayOfWeek` enum?

Comment: Works fine for me @Marijn.  This works, but I'll change my property to list, then de-dup internally to the object.  It's  a convenience object anyway, so I don't really want the Spring config to be this complicated.